# Can I use group_by method in ruby on rails by multi table?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `@schedules` Object in my shift table app

and I group it use group_by method in my controller

```
@schedules = Schedule.all
@days_off_list = @schedules.group_by {|t| t.staff}
```

Model:

```
class Staff
 has_many :schedules
end

class Schedule
 belongs_to :staff
end
```

I want it to display like [image: excel]

but I use the html tag `<table>`, and layout it like

> Jacky
>
> 2017-4-6 day off
>
> 2017-4-7 day off
>
> Allen
>
> 2017-4-4 day off
>
> 2017-4-6 day off

In my view:

```
<table>
<% @days_off_list.each do |staff, schedules| %> 
    <tr>
        <th><%= staff.name %></th>
    </tr>
    <% schedules.each do |schedule| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= schedule.days_off.to_date %></td>
            <td> break</td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I know how to group the @schedules by date by `if else` and group by attribute use group_by method, but I don't know how to use two ways together.

does I have any solution to solve the problem by group_by method or the other function?

Comment: Can you add your models, and models attributes?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I have added the models code

Answer (score 0):

I try the other ways to solve the question, and it can work.
the solutions is using three `each` loop and one `if` `elsif` to select the true date like what i write at above.

controller:

```
@staffs = Staff.all
@range = Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month
@schedules = Schedule.all
```

helper:

```
def search_days_off(day)
     Schedule.where(days_off: day.midnight..day.end_of_day).map {|t| t.staff.number}.sort.last
end
```

view:

```
<tbody>
        <% @range.each do |days| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= days %></td>
            <% @staffs.each do |staff| %>
                <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
                    <% if days == schedule.days_off.to_date %>
                        <% if staff.number ==  schedule.staff.number %>
                        <td>day off</td>
                        <% break %>
                        <% elsif schedule.staff.number.equal?(search_days_off(schedule.days_off)) %>
                        <td> </td>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```